# AX 2012 R3 AIF System Services Callcontext of another user

Tags: c#, dynamics-ax-2012, aif, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

Is it possible to call the AIF system services using a callcontext of another user?
I specifically need to fetch which tables a user has access to. By using the method `GetAccessRights` in the `UserSessionService`, I can extract which tables I have access to.
I need to call this for other users, so I tried setting the `CallContext.LogonAsUser` to another user, but I get the error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Failed to logon to Microsoft Dynamics AX.

To be able to use LogonAsUser on custom services, I need to set the "Trusted intermediary users" on the inbound port. However, it doesn't seem to be possible to set this on the system services.

I'm testing this on a contoso image. I'm logged in as contoso\Administrator.

The complete code:

```
USSReference.UserSessionServiceClient client = new USSReference.UserSessionServiceClient();

USSReference.CallContext context = new USSReference.CallContext
{
    LogonAsUser = "VishwaR"
};

USSReference.AccessControlledItemKey key = new USSReference.AccessControlledItemKey();
key.ItemType = USSReference.AccessControlledType.Table;
key.ItemName = "CUSTTABLE";

UserService.USSReference.AccessRight[] rights = client.GetAccessRights(context, new USSReference.AccessControlledItemKey[] { key });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create custom *AIF Inbound Port* and add `AifUserSessionService.GetAccessRights` operation. 
Here you can set `Allow trusted intermediary to impersonate`.

[image: Custom AIF service operation]